# Cardinality of set of well-orderable subsets of a non-well-orderable set

Tags: set-theory, axiom-of-choice

Suppose, with the negation of Axiom of Choice, we have a non-well-orderable set $A$, and its power set $P(A)$, 
let $P'(A)$ be $\{x \in P(A): x \text{ is well orderable}\}$

Is there an injection from  $P'(A)$ into $A$?

What can we say about the cardinality of $P'(A)$?

Comment: You mean *well-orderable*, right?

Comment: Are you understanding the set $A$ to be linearly ordered?  Or maybe partially ordered?  Or what?

Comment: If $A$ is partially ordered in such a way that every pair of its members is incomparable, then the only subsets well ordered by that  partial ordering (i.e. by its restriction) are singletons.  In that case there is an injection such as you seek.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Thank your for pointing that out.

Comment: The question is much clearer, and very different, after the latest edits.

Comment: @MichaelHardy:My bad.

Comment: What is a non-well-orderable set? In case it is what it looks like it is, what about the Well-ordering theorem?

Comment: @GitGud It seems the OP wants to work in $ZF$, without choice.

Comment: @GitGud: If the axiom of choice fails then there are sets which cannot be well-ordered.

Comment: @MettaWorldPeace I realise that. I just don't see anywhere in the question stating that we're in $ZF$ without $C$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me denote this set as $\mathcal W(A)$, which is a notation I recall seeing before (although not where, at the moment).

Clearly if $A$ can be well-ordered then $\mathcal W(A)=\mathcal P(A)$ and therefore we cannot *prove* that $\mathcal W(A)<\mathcal P(A)$, or that $|A|=|\mathcal W(A)|$. But it is also clear that if $A$ cannot be well-ordered then $\mathcal W(A)\neq\mathcal P(A)$.

- It is **consistent** that $|\mathcal W(A)|<|\mathcal P(A)|$:

  Suppose that $A$ is [infinite and] **amorphous** (cannot be written as a disjoint union of two infinite sets) then every well-orderable subset is finite. However $\mathcal P(A)$ is Dedekind-finite, so the cardinality of all finite subsets of $A$ is strictly smaller than that of $\mathcal P(A)$ (in fact it is exactly half!), and so it is consistent that the inequality is sharp.
- It is **provable** that $|A|<|\mathcal W(A)|$:

  1. Tarski, A. **[On well-ordered subsets of any set](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/fm/fm32/fm32115.pdf)**. *Fundamenta Mathematicae* **32**, pp. 176–183 (1939);
  2. Truss, J. K. **[The well-ordered and well-orderable subsets of a set](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/malq.19730191402/abstract)**. *Mathematical Logic Quarterly* **19**, pp. 211–214 (1973).

  You could also find a paragraph in L. Halbeisen's **[Combinatorial Set Theory](http://user.math.uzh.ch/halbeisen/publications/pdf/cst.pdf)**, *Chapter 5, Related Results no. 33.*

Comment: Zermelo gave a proof that $|A|<|\mathcal P(A)|$ that is essentially different from Cantor in that it avoids diagonalization. You can see it here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/284812/a-reverse-diagonal-argument/ That proof only uses $\mathcal W(A)$, so in fact Zermelo's argument gives the inequality $|A|<|\mathcal W(A)|$.

Comment: Stevo Todorcevic developed a nice theory of partition calculus of partially ordered sets in "Partition relations for partially ordered sets", Acta Math. 155 (1-2), (1985), 1–25. At the beginning of the paper, Stevo reproves $|A|<|\mathcal W(A)|$ as a consequence of very general results in his partition calculus setting.

Comment: Andres, thank you for the addition!