# Why those who dislike the fact that the reals are uncountable always attack Cantor's diagonal proof?

Tags: soft-question, infinity

For reasons that I never understood, the fact that there are several sizes of infinity and, in particular, the fact that the reals are uncountable is unacceptable for certain persons. My question is: why is it that those who try to refute that assertion always (or so it seems to me) point their guns at Cantor's diagonal proof? After all:

1. Cantor himself proved (before creating the diagonal proof) that the reals are uncountable by another method (based upon the fact that, in $\mathbb R$, every bounded monotonic sequence converges).
2. There are [other proofs](http://people.math.gatech.edu/~mbaker/pdf/realgame.pdf) that the reals are uncountable.

A few years ago, [Wilfrid Hodges](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilfrid_Hodges), a logician, wrote an interesting article about nearly the same question, called *[An Editor Recalls Some Hopeless Papers](http://www.logic.univie.ac.at/~ykhomski/ST2013/Hodges.pdf)*, but his article was about the validity (or lack thereof) of certain “refutations” of Cantor's diagonal argument. But my question is: why don't they try to refute the other arguments? Is it just because the diagonal argument is so well-known? Or is there some other reason?

Comment: I don't have any sources for this, but I suspect you have things somewhat backwards. Most of these people don't start thinking the reals are countable and then attack the proof; they don't understand the diagonal proof that is shown to them, and they attack it.

Comment: @MarkS. That's an interestaing possibility indeed.

Comment: That it is one of the most known proofs doesn't hurt.  It also relies very heavily on the Axiom of Choice.  Some people don't trust that axiom.  I once took a graduate philosophy of logic course.  The philosophy students were fine with other proofs, but mistrusted this one the most.

Comment: @JoeJohnson126 [No](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/304378/do-you-need-the-axiom-of-choice-to-accept-cantors-diagonal-proof), it does *not* rely on the Axiom of Choice (heavily or otherwise).

Comment: I think that part of the answer is indeed because it is the best known one ... and many people (including myself!) believe it was the first one, i.e they believe it is the one that, historically, upset the apple cart. But the nature of the proof has a lot to do with it as well ... we can conceptually relate to it (that is, there is not a lot of complex math involved), yet also easily misunderstood (because of the proof by contradiction style), and it is one that is easily misapplied to 'show' that the set of all natural numbers is not countable either. So yes, it is an easy and obvious target.

Comment: @JoeJohnson126 I don't see where AC comes in when for every given $f\colon A\to P(A)$, we explicitly construct $B\subseteq A$ such that $f(x)\ne B$ for all $x\in A$.

Comment: @Bram28 A I wrote in my question, it was *not* the first one.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Aha! So you can put me in that group of people that mistakenly believe that it was the first one :) And I am sure I am not the only one ... so as long as many *believe* it was the first one, it's still a target

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos And thanks for correcting me on that belief! :)

Comment: There are even plenty of mathematicians who don't "believe" in the real numbers to begin with, or who are at the very least agnostic: for most number theorists, algebraists, combinatorialists, and algebraic geometers, and even analysts working with special functions, the existence or not of the real numbers is of purely, er..., academic interest. The mathematics that's important to them could equally well be done with, for example, computable real numbers. There is one famous example who doesn't even "believe" in the integers. He is not a crank, though he might be cranky.

Comment: ...in other words, you might be begging the question with the first sentence of your post: it depends on what the meanings of "are" are.

Comment: @Stephen Though even for those who "believe" only in computable reals, these are uncountable in the sense that there is to *computable* enumeration of them ...

Comment: This is a quote regarding the reduction of the "philosophically unwanted or embarrassing" natural numbers into purely logical constructs: "One may dispute the philosophical significance of the reduction, but one knows exactly what one is talking about when one disputes it", and I provide that quote because in this instance it seems the dispute is instead with the (diagonal) argument and not the meaning - which is suggested by @MarkS. also. But I still wonder if the need to attack at all is at some level intuitive discomfort with the continuum combined with a lack of "philisophical meaningness"

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen That's true! ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: So for example in the Hodge article where the he states: "They all regarded Cantor's argument as an attempt at a deductive proof of a meaningful proposition" - I just suspect they might be fooling themselves, I think on some level there is a discomfort with the meaning of the proposition, and the diagonal argument may be the first point of attack because it is the argument involving an activity which could be conceived of being meaningful (writing out lists) leading to a conflict

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen The proof I have in mind is to line up all the reals between $0$ and $1$, then choose a different value for each numeral along the diagonal.  This number is not on the list.  I feel this requires countable choice.

Comment: @JoeJohnson126 It does not use countable choice at all. It's a bit easier to think about showing that the set $S$ of *infinite binary sequences* is uncountable (these aren't quite the same as the reals in $[0, 1]$ since dyadic fractions have two binary expansions, but not a big deal). The proof goes as follows: if we have a function, $f:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow S$, then let $\alpha_f$ be the sequence whose $n$th bit is $0$ if the $n$th bit of $f(n)$ is $1$, and $1$ if the $n$th bit of $f(n)$ is $0$. Then clearly $\alpha_f\not\in ran(f)$. Choice is never used in any form, at all. (cont'd)

Comment: So no $f:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow S$ could possibly be surjective, that is, $S$ is uncountable. Note that if we think of this as a "game" between Skeptic and Prover, Skeptic supplies $f$ and then Prover supplies $\alpha_f$; Prover doesn't care where Skeptic got their $f$ from. I think when you write "The proof I have in mind is to line up all the reals between $0$ and $1$, then choose a different value for each numeral along the diagonal," you're forgetting how the proof goes and thinking that we want to construct the list as well as the real not on the list, and this isn't true.

Answer (score 9):

While *you* are familiar with other proofs, and that the diagonal proof wasn't even the first one, this is not so for many other people (I myself did not know it wasn't the first one until you corrected me in the comments)

So, to many people this *is* the only proof they know, and even if they do know there are other proofs, they believe it is the first one, it is the one most commonly presented, and conceptually it is the easiest to understand one.

Cantor's first proof, for example, may just be too technical for many people to understand, so they don't attack it, even if they do know of it. But the diagonal proof is one we can all conceptually relate to, even as some of us misunderstand the subtleties in the argument. In fact, missing these subtleties is what often leads the attackers to mistakenly claim that the diagonal argument can also be used to show that the natural numbers are not countable and thus must be rejected.

And finally, believing this proof was the first one makes it an emotional target: this one is seen to have upset the apple cart!  Grrr! It is almost like an ad hominem fallacy, or the fallacy of shooting the messenger.