# A question about proving that there is no greatest cardinal

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

I would like to know if it is possible to prove that there is no greatest cardinal **without** axiom of choice

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/304378/do-you-need-the-axiom-of-choice-to-accept-cantors-diagonal-proof ; http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/284812/a-reverse-diagonal-argument/284834#284834

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is just Hartogs theorem, stating that if $X$ is any set, then there is an ordinal which admits no injections into $X$.

If $\alpha$ is any ordinal, then $\alpha$ can be mapped into $\mathcal P(\alpha)$, which has a larger cardinality, so by Hartogs theorem there is an ordinal of cardinality larger than $\alpha$. Namely, if $\alpha$ was a cardinal, then there has to be a larger cardinal than $\alpha$.

It should also be noted that without the axiom of choice, the class of cardinals contains *more* than just ordinals. So appealing toe Cantor's theorem works just fine, as it ensures that there is no *maximal* cardinal.